# What are all the rules (cross browser if possible) that deal with when autocomplete will turn on in an input field?

Tags: html, css, search, autocomplete

I turned on search for our site and went to test it for the first time and boom previous search terms I had used on other websites have come up.   I thought this was related to "name".   I have the very unique name of "search" so figured... must be it.

Then I notice that one of the autocompletes is my zipcode and I doubt someone named the zipcode input field "search".   So then I go to the advanced search page and boom same exact "name" but none of the autocompletes from other sites showing up.

So what are the rules (html/css/browser) governing when autocomplete shows?   Also how can I tie my regular search input box to the advanced search box so when someone searches for something from one spot on our site it shows in the other?

Comment: Could you post the markup from both these search fields? If you want to read up about it instead, here's a comprehensive article: https://cloudfour.com/thinks/autofill-what-web-devs-should-know-but-dont/

Comment: Do you mean the following: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/input/forms/#recommended_input_name_and_autocomplete_attribute_values

Comment: @FranCarstens - I have read that stuff before but there is more to it.   If I have a "name" but with a different class sometimes it seems like it carries over and others it doesn't.

Comment: @blankip, without seeing the markup it's hard to guess what's going on. Could be related to [autocomplete attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete). As to the second part of your question, that'll probably need to be another post, showing code and demonstrating what you've done so far.